# Knowing that A is similar to B, find an invertible matrix such that P^−1AP = B.

Tags: matrices, inverse, similar-matrices

Knowing that A and B are similar, where A and B are 2x2 matrices [image], how would I go about finding an invertible matrix P^-1 such that P^−1AP = B.

I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Since $A$ and $B$ both have rank $1$, this should be easier than doing it for general $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: How would you go about finding P in that case?

Comment: Note that $A$ is symmetric and its eigenvectors are easy to compute. You need only define $P$ on two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: That is what I thought; however, the P that I get using the eigenvectors of A, in the equation P^-1AP = diagonal matrix, not B.
What do you think might have gone wrong?

Comment: Now that you've diagonalized $A$, it might help to diagonalize $B$ while you're at it.

Comment: I think I have solved for eigenvalues of both A and B and for their related eigenspaces, I have constructed the P and D matrices for both, but still connot find P such that it satisfies the initial equation P-1AP=B